# Failed recursion on a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, recursion

**Context.** I am trying to rotate a matrix by 90 degrees clockwise in-place using Numpy using recursion. Each iteration of the `rotate()` function rotates the "outer rim" of the input `matrix`.

**Question.** At the beginning of the second iteration, `matrix` seems to evaluate to `[]`. Why does this happen? (I think it is a problem with memory storage, but I am not sure...) When I try printing `np.ndarray.tolist(matrix[np.ix_(range(1,n-1),range(1,n-1))]))` at the end of the first iteration, I get the correct submatrix.

Source code:

```
def rotate(matrix):
   
    n = len(matrix)
    print(f"matrix = {matrix}\n")
    x = matrix[0]
    matrix = np.asarray(matrix)
    x = np.asarray(x)

    # rotate outer rim

    for i in range(1,n):
        matrix[0,i-1] = matrix[n-i,0]
    matrix[0,n-1] = x[0]

    for i in range(1,n):
        matrix[i,0] = matrix[n-1,i]

    for i in range(1,n):
        matrix[n-1,i] = matrix[n-i-1,n-1]

    for i in range(1,n):
        matrix[i,n-1] = x[i]

    # 

    return f"{
    rotate(list(np.ndarray.tolist(matrix[np.ix_(range(1,n-1),range(1,n-1))])))
    }\n"

    # apply recursion to inner submatrix 
    # error: the indices DO NOT get reset when taking submatrices
    
    return matrix
```

Error message:

```
x = matrix[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

### Edit:

Sample inputs and outputs:

```
Input: matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
Output: [[7,4,1],[8,5,2],[9,6,3]]

Input: matrix = [[5,1,9,11],[2,4,8,10],[13,3,6,7],[15,14,12,16]]
Output: [[15,13,2,5],[14,3,4,1],[12,6,8,9],[16,7,10,11]]
```

- The matrix is always a square matrix.
- There isn't a deep reason why I am using iterations for this particular solution. (I am working on a different solution which uses other techniques.)

Comment: Why using iterations? Is this homework? Can you provide an unambiguous data sample and the expected output for clarity? Is the matrix always square?

Comment: This is not homework. This is a leetcode problem ("Rotate Image") that I am doing for practice. I've edited the original post in response to your questions.

Comment: OK, so you want to replicate `np.rot90(matrix, -1)` ;)

Comment: Some things to think about: 1) What is the "bottom" case for the recursion? 2) You are creating new objects at each recursive call; converting from a NumPy array to a list and back again. Where do your changes go?

Comment: For future readers, the link to original problem is: https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-easy/92/array/770/

Comment: `np.asarray` does not make a copy (if the input is itself an array).  On the other hand going through `tolist` will make a copy.  Keeping track of when an object is changed in-place, and when it's a copy, is especially important when doing recursion.  It matters too when doing iterations, but it's easier to track.

Comment: `for i in range(1,n): matrix[i,n-1] = x[i]` can be written as `matrix[:,n-1] = x`.  Assuming `matrix` and `x` are `ndarray` (not list or strings), there's no need to do these low level iterations.